# Problem of retrieving username and password using Ajax and Java

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am using Ajax in a jsp page wherein we have a form of filling with Username and Password. I am able to retrieve them in the same page. But while passing it to a Servlet i.e. Admin.java file both username and password are not been passed.

Code:

```
function prepareLoginDialog(){
        $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Enter the login details here :">'+
            'User: <input type="text" id="u" name="u" ></input><br />'+
            'Pass: <input type="password" id="p" name="p" ></input>'+
            '</div>')

            //System.out.println(user);
        //System.out.println(pass);
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Login',
            buttons: {
                'Login': function() {
                    //Send Login Request to Server
                    var user = document.getElementById("u").value;
                    var pass = document.getElementById("p").value;
                    alert(user);
                    alert(pass);
                    //System.out.println(u.text);
                    login(user,pass);

                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
```

The Login Function is:

```
function login(user, pass) {
        //ToDo: User Login check
        alert(user);

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "Admin?action=login",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { username: user, password: pass },
            success: function(response){
                prepareLogoutDialog();
                prepareLoggedIn();
            }
        });
```

In the Java file it is

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("access", true);
            System.out.println("Admin:doGet:login:true");
            System.out.println("u");
            String userName = request.getParameter("u");

            String password = request.getParameter("p");
            System.out.println(userName);
            System.out.println(password);
```

Not getting printed.
Do I need to convert the username and password to string before passing? If so how do we do that?

Please help.

Comment: The values "u" and "p" don't appear to be passed as request parameters at all? Your AJAX request only includes their values in the data object - as "username" and "password".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect them as request parameters `u` and `p`, you should thus also pass them as such:

```
data: { u: user, p: pass },
```

or change your servlet to retrieve them with the given names in `data {}`

```
String userName = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

On the other hand, the `System.out.println()` prints to the stdout (which end up in logfile), not to the HTTP response. If you expect them in the response, so that it's available as content of `response` in `function(response)`, then you need to print to the HTTP response.

```
response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println(userName);
writer.println(password);
```

#### Related questions:

- [Update current page with a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet)

Comment: Should I point you to your own blogpost? Response encoding is missed.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. I am very happy for the quick response.